# Root "/" directory is consumed 100% and the system restarts, need to find the root cause as after the restart the usage is down to 75%

Tags: linux, disk-usage, monitoring

I am facing an issue that the system restarts after the following error is encountered and after the restart the usage is down to 75%.

> dfmon[16139]: CRITICAL: Disk Free Monitor: 102 #Filesystem "/" is 100%
>   full.

Is there any way to find the files which were consuming this space from any log or somewhere? Maybe any process is creating these files and I need to troubleshoot it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It could be due `/tmp` being automatically emptied during boot/shutdown (depending on configuration/distribution; is `/tmp` on `/`, what scripts are run, ...).

Comment: Yes, the /tmp is under /. But there are a lot of processes running as it is a Production Server. I need to know if there's any log where the files created on a system are written. Thanks.

Comment: It may well be unlinked but still open files.  I'm not sure what it means to "find" them.

Comment: Unless you have auditing enabled you will not have a log of all file creations. And if you think about it, on a reasonably busy system, the number of files created can be quite large. Think about temp files created by various processes, log files, etc. If you really want to know what files are open, `lsof` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see suspiciously large files in /tmp or another directory that might be emptied on boot, a probable cause are unlinked but still open files.

This is usually caused intentionally by some programs, e.g. to create shared memory that can be passed to other processes but not accessed by unrelated processes through a file name. It might also happen unintentionally if e.g. a log file is rotated/deleted but the logging process keeps the file open.

These files cease to exist when all processes die that are keeping the file open (so at the latest when cleanly shutting down the system) and when e.g. `fsck` is run after a power failure. So such files would explain that the usage goes down after rebooting.

Try this (as root) to see all deleted but still open files that were created on the mount point `/`:

```bash
lsof -s -- / | grep -e '^COMMAND \| (deleted)' | less
```

The column `COMMAND` contains the name of the process keeping the file open, `SIZE` the file size in bytes and `NAME` the path the file had originally before it was deleted.

If you see an extremely big file or file names typical for log files in the list then you probably got your culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It may take a while since your drive is full. It checks all files under root and then sorts by size.

```
du / | sort -n
```

If it takes to long then just get a summary and repeat until you can drill down.

```
du -s /* | sort -n
```

Comment: Hi @Jeight, thanks but as I mentioned earlier, after the restart, the space is back to normal so there are no files present which caused the restart in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The package manager often has a cache, that takes a few gigs. `sudo yum clean all` or `sudo apt-get clean all` can clear some stuff up.

`du` is a great tool. I'd use `du -xhd1 /`

`-x, --one-file-system
-h, --human-readable
-d, --max-depth=N`

Don't go crazy deleting stuff though.  I'd find where your server application is writing data to, and make sure it's logs aren't out of control